# Why doesn't this String Handling work?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
inp = input("Enter word")
inplen = len(inp)

text = "sandwich"
textlen = len(text)

if inplen >= textlen:
    if inp[0] == text[0]:
        print("s")
if inplen >= textlen:
    if inp[1] == text[1]:
        print("a")
if inplen >= textlen:
    if inp[2] == text[2]:
        print("n")
if inplen >= textlen:
    if inp[3] == text[3]:
        print("d")
if inplen >= textlen:        
    if inp[4] == text[4]:
        print("w")
if inplen >= textlen:        
    if inp[5] == text[5]:
        print("i")
if inplen >= textlen:        
    if inp[6] == text[6]:
        print("c")
if inplen >= textlen:
    if inp[7] == text[7]:
        print("h")
```

I don't get an output when I don't enter the full "sandwich". What I'm trying to do is that the program should print all the correct letters that have been entered that match "sandwhich". So when entering "sandwooh" they program should return "s" "a" "n" "d" "w" "h" and when entering "sand" it should return "s" "a" "n" "d".
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop would be much easier here:

```
text = "sandwich"
inp = input("Enter word")

# a range from zero to the length of the shortest string
# (if one string is longer than the other, we want the length of the shortest
#  one so that it doesn't try to check characters that don't exist)
for i in range(min(len(text), len(inp))):
    # print if corresponding characters match
    if inp[i] == text[i]:
        print(text[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that as follows:

```
in_text = str(input("Enter word: "))
print(list(set(input) & set('sandwich')))
```

`set(a) & set(b)` returns a set that contains elements that are common to both `a` and `b`. `list()` then converts them to a list and then you print them. Here is an example:

```
>>> print(list(set('sandstorm') & set('sandwich')))
['s', 'a', 'n', 'd']
```

Comment: This will fail if the word has duplicate characters, such as `potato`.

Comment: @Doorknob, But doesn't the OP just want letters that they inputted right? Like hangman, doesn't matter how many times the character actually occurs.

Comment: @Doorknob, Maybe I didn't understand you properly. Can you please give an example of what you mean? Thanks